# About servo and ultra with fire-base

Tags: c++, arduino, servo

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Servo.h>


Servo servo1;
int trigPin=D1;
int echoPin=D2;
long distance;
long duration;

void setup(){

    servo1.attach(D3);

    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

   Serial.begin(115200);

WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

Serial.print("connecting");

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {

Serial.print(".");

delay(500);

}

Serial.println();

Serial.print("connected: ");

Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());                                    

    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST,FIREBASE_AUTH);
    Firebase.set("SERVO_STATUS",0);
    Firebase.set("Variable/Value",1);
}

long getDistance(){

    digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(trigPin,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);
    long duration=pulseIn(echoPin,HIGH);
    long distance=duration*0.034/2;
    return distance;
}


void loop(){

   int n=Firebase.getInt("Variable/Value");
   int x=Firebase.getInt("SERVO_STATUS");

   if(x==0)
   {           
       if (n==1 && getDistance()<=10)
       {
           servo1.write(100);
           delay(4000);
       }

       else
       {
           servo1.write(0);
           delay(1000);
       }
   }

   else
   {
        servo1.write(100);
        delay(1000);
   }
}
```

I wrote this code to when the ultra sonic sens something and trigger the servo motor and i made app to on and off the motor via fire base .... when i press the off button in the app it will close the servo motor but after few second it will automatically open and starts to continuously working.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify in which condition you want to write value 100 and in which 0?

Comment: um making a smart dustbin,  so i need to stop the servo motor after the dustbin percentage reached 100% (when it become 100 it will also send a 0 to the value in firebase)and also it will not open until i press the button and turn the value in 0 to 1 (when the )

Comment: I don't get the point of the last else block

Comment: what do you meant by last else block

Comment: This part: `else
   {
        servo1.write(100);
        delay(1000);
   }`

Comment: that if  x = 1 (SERVO_STATUS)

Comment: **yes the same behavior can you gimme a hand to fix that**